# Prolog: user input and multiple outputs

Tags: prolog, user-input

```
student(foo).
student(bar).
```

KB

```
ask(Q) :- ask(Q,A).
ask(Q,A) :- .....
```

ask(Q,A) takes a question in a form of linked list generated by getsentence(S).

```
run(A) :-
  write('enter question/statement: '),
  getsentence(S), nl,
  ask(S,A). 

/*
1 ?- ask([who,is,a,student],A).
A = foo ;
A = bar ;
false.

2 ?- run(A).
enter question/statement:who is a student.


A = foo .

*/
```

Only one result shows up instead of multiple as an output. I feel like I am missing something very simple but I have no clue what it is.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
findall(A, ask(S,A), AllAnswers).
```

instead of

```
ask(S,A).
```

In this way AllAnswers will match a list of all possible values of A when ask(S,A) succeeds.